# iOS realm Results<Object> can't add Results<Project>

Tags: ios, swift3, realm

I try to create universal UITableView dataSource class for realm Results, but when i try to send realmResults different from
Results<<>Object<>> on example Results i got this error message:

> Cannot convert value of type 'Results'<'Project'>' to expected element type 'Results'<'Object'>'

```
class RealmResultsTableViewDataSource: TableViewDataSource {

var realmResults:[Results<Object>]
var notificationTokens: [NotificationToken] = []

init(tableView: UITableView, realmResults: [Results<Object>], configCell: @escaping TableViewConfigCellBlock, canEdit: TableViewCanEditCellBlock?, canMove: TableViewCanMoveRowBlock?, commitEditing: TableViewCommitEditingStyleBlock?) {

    self.realmResults = realmResults

    super.init(tableView: tableView, dataSource: [], configCell: configCell, canEdit: canEdit, canMove: canMove, commitEditing: commitEditing)

    addTokens(for: realmResults)
}

deinit {
    for token in notificationTokens {
        token.stop()
    }
}

override var sections: Int{
    get { return realmResults.count }
}

override func numberOfRows(section: Int) -> Int {
    return realmResults[section].count
}

// MARK: Add tokens

func addTokens(for results: [Results<Object>]) {
    for result in results {

       let notificationToken = result.addNotificationBlock { [weak self] (changes: RealmCollectionChange) in
            guard let tableView = self?.tableView else { return }
            switch changes {
            case .initial:
                // Results are now populated and can be accessed without blocking the UI
                tableView.reloadData()
                break
            case .update(_, let deletions, let insertions, let modifications):
                // Query results have changed, so apply them to the UITableView
                tableView.beginUpdates()
                tableView.insertRows(at: insertions.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }),
                                     with: .automatic)
                tableView.deleteRows(at: deletions.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0)}),
                                     with: .automatic)
                tableView.reloadRows(at: modifications.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }),
                                     with: .automatic)
                tableView.endUpdates()
                break
            case .error(let error):
                // An error occurred while opening the Realm file on the background worker thread
                fatalError("\(error)")
                break
            }
        }

        notificationTokens.append(notificationToken)
    }
}

override func dataSourceObject(on indexPath: IndexPath) -> Any {

    return realmResults[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
}
```

}

And:

let realm = try! Realm()

```
    let result = realm.objects(Project.self).filter("id < 10").sorted(byKeyPath: "id", ascending: true)

    tableViewDataSource = RealmResultsTableViewDataSource(tableView: tableView, realmResults: [result], configCell: { (tableView, indexPath, object) -> UITableViewCell in

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:ProjectListTableViewCell.cellIdentifier , for: indexPath)

        return cell

    }, canEdit: nil, canMove: nil, commitEditing: nil)



import RealmSwift

class Project: Object {

    dynamic var id: Int = 0
    dynamic var name: String = ""
}
```

Solution:

```
class RealmResultsTableViewDataSource<T: Object>: TableViewDataSource {

    var realmResults:Results<T>
    var notificationTokens: [NotificationToken] = []


    init(tableView: UITableView, realmResults: Results<T>, configCell: @escaping TableViewConfigCellBlock, canEdit: TableViewCanEditCellBlock?, canMove: TableViewCanMoveRowBlock?, commitEditing: TableViewCommitEditingStyleBlock?) {

        self.realmResults = realmResults

        super.init(tableView: tableView, dataSource: [], configCell: configCell, canEdit: canEdit, canMove: canMove, commitEditing: commitEditing)


        addTokens(for: self.realmResults)
    }

    deinit {

        for token in notificationTokens {
            token.stop()
        }
    }

    override var sections: Int{

        get{
          return 1
        }
    }

    override func numberOfRows(section: Int) -> Int {
        return realmResults.count
    }


    // MARK: Add tokens

    func addTokens(for results: Results<T>) {

           let notificationToken = results.addNotificationBlock { [weak self] (changes: RealmCollectionChange) in
                guard let tableView = self?.tableView else { return }
                guard tableView.dataSource === self else { return }
                switch changes {
                case .initial:
                    // Results are now populated and can be accessed without blocking the UI
                    tableView.reloadData()
                    break
                case .update(_, let deletions, let insertions, let modifications):
                    // Query results have changed, so apply them to the UITableView
                    tableView.beginUpdates()
                    tableView.insertRows(at: insertions.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }),
                                         with: .automatic)
                    tableView.deleteRows(at: deletions.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0)}),
                                         with: .automatic)
                    tableView.reloadRows(at: modifications.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }),
                                         with: .automatic)
                    tableView.endUpdates()
                    break
                case .error(let error):
                    // An error occurred while opening the Realm file on the background worker thread
                    fatalError("\(error)")
                    break
                }
            }

            notificationTokens.append(notificationToken)
    }

    override func dataSourceObject(on indexPath: IndexPath) -> Any {

        return realmResults[indexPath.row]
    }

    override func removeObject(indexPath: IndexPath) {
       // assertionFailure("you can use ramoveObject int \(String(describing: self))")
    }

}
```

Comment: Please improve your code formatting. You will get better answers that way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, Realm Swift does not support polymorphism, yet.

> The current solution is to use composition instead of inheritance.
>   There are lots of good argument about it (Gang of Four and Joshua
>   Bloch to mention some prestigious supporters of this approach).
>
> On the other hand we are considering to allow inheritance, but it
>   would not allow queries. For example: Animal which is extended both by
>   Dog, Cat and Duck. You would not be able to query Animals with for
>   legs and have all Dogs and Cats, but not Ducks. We feel this would be
>   a very crippling behavior but are eager to listen to more opinions.

This is discussed here (this discuss the java version of the product, so it's only a starting point for you...): https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/761

The simplest solution [but perhaps not the best if you need to reuse these methods with other subclasses of Object]  for you would be to replace
"Object" with "Project"

Comment: Thanks for your help, I managed to find a solution using a generic class

Comment: That's awesome! Glad you're back on track!